# how i redirect to different jsp page(not redirect to login page) after my session timeout in spring boot security

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am added this in `server.servlet.session.timeout=60s` in my`application.properties` file. whenever my timeout happens if  press any action my page directly moved to login page and I don't want redirect to login page i want to redirect to different  page like (`home.jsp`).how to do it in spring security?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, for more details on topic visit this page https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-logout

```java
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.logout()
                // other HTTP configurations are removed for simplicity
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") // here you can put your redirect URL
                .permitAll();
    }
```

Note: note that you have to and() above config. If you have any other configurations for http in place.